# Eclipse mapped network drives gone/not found

Tags: eclipse, mapped-drive

since I couldn't find a relevant topic on this...

Eclipse doesn't find my mapped network drives anymore. I can access them through explorer, but Eclipse seems unable to connect/recognize them: they just appear to be absent in Eclipse.

[image: drives present in explorer]

[image: drives absent in eclipse]

Comment: Does it work in new eclipse instances(new workspace) ???

Comment: nope... strange thing is: i have a shortcut to a folder on one of the network directories...and that is visible....

Comment: Does it work on Linux ???

Comment: at least I got the 'tumbleweed' achievement

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?